# Bubble Sort Algorithm in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, bubble-sort

The program I"m trying to finish is a program using the bubble sort algorithm.  I am not sure what is the problem or in which function the problem is in.  The problem is the program does not sort the array in properly.  (It also must be arranged in ascending order).

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"

void getArray (int arr[], int size);
void sortArray (int arr[], int size);
void swap (int arr[], int num, int number);
void dispArray (int arr[], int size);
bool checkBigger (int arr[], int num, int number);

main()
{
          int size;

          printf("Enter number of elements: ");
          size=GetInteger();

          int arr[size];
          getArray(arr, size);
          sortArray(arr, size);
          dispArray(arr, size);

          getchar();
}

void getArray (int arr[], int size)
{
          int num;    

          printf("Please enter the value of the elements: \n");
          for(num=0; num<size; num++)
          {
                     arr[num]=GetInteger();           
          }    
}

void sortArray (int arr[], int size)
{
          int num, number, d;

          for(num=0;num<size-1;num++)
          {
              for(d=0; d<size-num-1; d++)
              {
                     number=num+1;                
                     checkBigger(arr, num, number);              
              }
          }
}

void swap (int arr[], int num, int number)
{
          int tem;

          tem=arr[num];
          arr[num]=arr[number];
          arr[number]=tem;
}

void dispArray (int arr[], int size)
{
          int num;

          printf("The sorted list is:\n");
          for(num=0; num<size; num++)
          {
                      printf("%d\t", arr[num]);         
          }     
}

bool checkBigger (int arr[], int num, int number)
{     
          if(arr[num]>arr[number])
          {
                      swap(arr, num, number);                     
          }     
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Find out the problem and then ask for explanation/solution. What's the output ? Have you tried to add some debug ?

Comment: SO is not for code review. Do you have a specific technical question?

Comment: One skill to aquire is to debug your code. Test the individual functions if they do what you expect. (far goal: learn about unit tests). See what is going on (near goal: add output with vital information during the program execution). Invest time to master the use of a debugger to be able to step through the code during execution (mid term goal).

Comment: My question is that why when I enter the 5 values 78 34 65 33 21, do I get a sorted list of 34 65 33 21 78.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void sortArray (int arr[], int size)
{
    int num, number, d;

    for(num=0;num<size-1;num++)
    {
        for(d=0; d<size-num-1; d++)
        {
            number=d+1;
            checkBigger(arr, d, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this program works fine now =), but I still don't understand why we use d?

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner `checkBigger(arr, num, number);` inner loop `num` and `number` always same value.

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure your problem is with you algorithm, try to simulate your algorithm in pen and paper. it will help your understanding of your code and the algorithm better :)

for your convenience here i am including a bubble sort algorithm i did some while ago

```
void bubbleSort( int a[], int n)
{
    int i,j,temp; // for a={1,2,3,4,5} n is 5

    n = n - 1;    // bcz otherwise it will get out of index

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n-i; j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                temp = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = a[j];
               a[j] = temp;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

i hope this helps

Comment: Yes thank you very much, now I can see that I have to use d instead of labelling it num :)

Answer (score 1):

All I follow from the above examples is an implementation of the exchange sort.

The exchange sort on the outer loop checks each entry in the table against the first element, exchanging when necessary.  At then end of the inner loop, the lowest element is in position 1, then it begins with position 2, comparing it to the remaining elements, and doing an exchange.  Even if the array was already in order, the sort cannot stop.  It has to do a n*(n-1) compares. An array of 50 elements, already sorted will do 50*49 comparisons.

The bubble sort works differently

set a swap flag to zero. Then 
slide along the array, comparing position(i) to position(i+1).  If a swap takes place, you do the sort again.

here is some pseudo code.

1. swap = 0
2. do {
3. for (i=o;i< no-elements-1;i++) {
4. if (array[i] > array[i+1])
5. {
6. do the exchange
7. set swap=1
8. }
9. /**/
10. } while (swap == 1);

The above illustrates the bubble sort.

Note. if the data is in order, there is no swap and there is no second loop.   The sort algorithm is able to quit early.

if a fifty element array is in order, the sort would have done 50 comparisons and would have stopped.
The exchange sort, which is described earlier would have to do 50*49 or 2450 comparisons.

Comment: I have written a sample bubble sort program that is about 20 lines.I would like to attach it here but am not aware of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//   BUBBLE SORT.
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
int main()
{
    int arr[MAX];int no;

    printf("PLEASE ENTER THE CURRENT SIZE OF THE ARRAY\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&no);

    int i;
    printf("PLEASE ENTER THE ELEMENTS OF THE ARRAY\n");
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);  /*reading the elements*/

    /* sorting begins*/
    int j,k,l;
    int temp;
    int flag=0;

    for(k=0;k<no-1;k++)
        {
        flag=0;
        j=k;
        for(i=0;i<no-j-1;i++)  /* not going to the part that has been sorted*/
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
                flag=1;
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp;
            }
            else 
                continue;/* not necessary*/
        }
        if(flag==0)  /*implies that the array is alraedy sorted*/
            break;
    }
    printf("THE SORTED LIST:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: I AM A BEGINNER. I JUST LEARNED THE ALGORITHMAND MADE SOME CHANGES AS MENTIONED IN THE COMMENT.

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    // This is a bubble sort algorithm
    int i, length; 
    printf("Enter the size of the array: "); 
    scanf("%d",&length); 
    int arr[length]; 
    printf("\n"); 
    for(i=0; i < length; i++) 
    { 
        printf("Enter %d. element of the array: ",i+1); 
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]); 
    } 
    
    // Loop of its size
    for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        // Break flag of change
        int changed = 1;
        // Loop of its size-n (n++) each time 
        for (int i = 0; i < length - n - 1; i++)
        {
            // Compare ith with i+1th element, if ith element is bigger than i+1th
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            {
                // Swap them
                int var = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = var;
                changed = 0;
            }
        
        }
        if (changed)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Sorted array: [");
    for (int l = 0; l < length - 1; l++)
    {
        printf("%i ", arr[l]);
    }
    printf("%i]\n", arr[length-1]);
    return 0;
}
```