# How to put in order random numbers

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have an excise to find a way to put random numbers in order inside an array.
the problem I have is how can I know if my numbers are in order so i can exit the loop.

I am allowed to use only loopes, arrays and conditions for this one.

```
while (!checker) {
  if (C[B_index] > C[B_index+1] && B_index < sizeB) {
    checker = C[B_index+1];
    C[B_index+1] = C[B_index];
    C[B_index] = checker;
    B_index++;
  }
  else if (B_index == sizeB)
    B_index = 0;
  else if (C[B_index] <= C[B_index+1])
    B_index++
}
```

Comment: Yourcodeisalittledifficulttoread,mainlybecauseofthelackofwhitespace.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a spellchecker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bubble Sort Algorithm in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655748/bubble-sort-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: `C[B_index]>C[B_index+1]` must be always false, isn't it?

Comment: Hint: Sort your data.  Upon completion of a sort, you know your data is in order so you can exit.  See the bubble sort link above.  Your code looks like a broken attempt at a bubble sort right now.

Comment: In `if(C[B_index]>C[B_index+1]&&B_index<sizeB)` you should test `B_index<sizeB` before the array is indexed, since accessing an array out-of-bounds may fault. And since you are also testing `C[B_index+1]` the condition should be `if(B_index < sizeB-1 && C[B_index] > C[B_index+1])`

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<SizeB;i++) if(C[i-1] > C[i]) {/*data is not in ascending order*/}`

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi  ok i will do it better next time

Comment: @gabi939, edit your question to do it better *this* time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use a loop inside a loop you can use this.
based on bubble-sort.
this way the program loops once on the array to find the bigget or smallest number (several variations of the same algorithm), next search is shorter by one so the break condition is set in the loops themselves. no need for another "if(...)"  for it.

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp     = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```