# Implementing bubble sort in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a sorting function which would sort the characters from an array. Can someone tell why it's not working?

```
int     main()
{
    char tab[] = {'e', 'b', 'd', 'z', 'a', 't', '\0'};
    char tab2[7] = {0};
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (tab[i] != '\0')
    {
        for (j = 0; tab[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (tab[i] > tab2[j])
            {
                tab2[k] = tab[j];
                k++;
            }

        }
        k=0;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", tab2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears that your sorting algorithm will populate all values of tab2 with the highest value in tab. This is not how sorting works.

Comment: There's no sorting algorithm here.  Why do you think this should work?

Comment: You've asked this exact question complete with exact same title in the wrong language  the other day. (ok, fine, you added two useless `!= '\0'`)

Comment: Bubble-sort is an in-place sorting algorithm, but you don't even try to change `tab`, so none of your code make sense. You ask what's wrong, and the answer is: All of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bubble Sort Algorithm in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655748/bubble-sort-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: sorry I didn't see it was a bubble sort for characters, see my answer.

Comment: Try understanding the logic and then implement your code accordingly. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 0):

You '\0' has value 0 while your letters have value of 97+ for lower cases letter, so once your array is sorted the '\0' is at the very beginning.

use `man ascii` in the terminal or check the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

You can initialize your final array values at 127 and then sort the following way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
  if (x != y)
  {
    *x ^= *y;
    *y ^= *x;
    *x ^= *y;
  }
}

int     main()
{
    char tab[] = {'e', 'b', 'd', 'z', 'a', 't', '\0'};
    char tab2[7];

    for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        tab2[l] = 127;

    tab2[6] = 0;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (tab[i] != '\0')
    {
        for (j = 0; tab[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (tab[i] < tab2[j]) // this is bubble sort, check if value is inferior
                swap(&tab[i], &tab2[j]); // if it is then swap pointers
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", tab2);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
abdetz
```