# Trying to sort and find median

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

My professor is making me write a function to find the median of an array of any given size. However, it isn't sorting correctly and gives the wrong value for the median. I'm not allowed to change anything in the parameter list.

I tried to bubble sort to put everything in ascending order but it does not change the array order at all. When I tell it to print median it prints a value from the array that's one off from where the median should be.

```
double vect_median(const double x[],unsigned length)
{
    double ans = 0;  
    for( unsigned i = 1; i < length ; ++i)
    { 
        double x_copy [length];
        //loops through array to copy to new array
        for(size_t j = 0; j < length - 1; ++j)
        {   
            //Copies x at index j to x_copy at index j
            x_copy[j] = x[j];   
        }
        //Loops through array to check for order
        for(size_t k = 0; k < length - 1; ++k)
        {   
            //Reorders if out of order
            if(x_copy[k] > x_copy[k + 1])
            {
                double temp = x_copy[k]; 
                x_copy[k] = x_copy[k + 1];
                x_copy[k + 1] = temp; 
            }
        }
        if(length % 2 == 0)
        {
            ans = (x_copy[(length-1)/2] + x_copy[length/2])/2.0;
        }
        else
        {
            ans = x_copy[length/2 - 1];
        }
    }
    return ans; 
}
```

Comment: The loop that copies to the new array is not copying the last element. the `for` condition should be `j < length;`

Comment: Your sorting loop is not correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655748/bubble-sort-algorithm-in-c

Comment: The answer for an odd-length array has an off-by-one error. For example, if `length` is 5, then `length/2` is 2, which is the correct index. The `- 1` needs to be removed.